# Hide CSR Item *before* it is displayed

Tags: client-side-rendering

Something simple? I have never needed before.

I want to **use the default Item rendering** in a ListView, but hide all items on initial display.

The OnPostRender function will then do its magic and show some Items.

The user then gets some buttons to do more filtering

I can't filter in the OnPreRender because all Items need to be displayed.

Doing the filter in the OnPostRender causes a nasty flash I would like to avoid

tnx

Comment: Can't you wire in some CSS on prerender to set the web part to display:none or add a class that displays none and on post render remove the class or do a toggle/fade in/etc?

Comment: Good thought, but I'd like this to be minimal impact, I don't have any control over the code after I release this. And needs to work in any page-layout. So it (preferably) needs to be just one CSR file (UserCustomAction ScriptLink)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Workaround #1

Erics suggestion, and my requirements to only target the one webpart got me this:

```
OnPreRender: function () {
    var element = document.createElement('STYLE');
    element.id = 'CSS' + ctx.view;
    element.innerText = "table[id$='" + ctx.view + "']{display:none}";
    document.head.appendChild(element);
    //do magic here
},
OnPostRender: function () {
    //do magic here
    document.querySelector("style[id='CSS" + ctx.view + "']").innerText = '';
}
```

It adds a named StyleSheet in the HEAD of the page (before any HTML content is displayed)
The STYLE targets the one WebPart, sets is to none

And deletes the CSS rules after all my processing is done

Comment: The other workaround would be javascript based, but essentially do the same thing, would allow you to do a smooth transition or animation.

Comment: In my full code I keep the STYLE element and a reference to it. By setting the innerText I can apply any CSS whenever I need. Because I add data-* attributes to my fields I can target them with one (a tat more complex) selector